# How to call a value at a specific index of a list in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to call a value at a specific index from a list. For an example index,
at index[2]. I can't seem how to figure how to do this. I can only get the value at the last index.

```
# number of arrivals per second
_lambda = 0.00923579

# number of AC arriving
_num_events = 10

_event_num = []
_inter_event_times = []
_event_times = []
_event_time = 0

for i in range(_num_events):
    _event_num.append(i)
    n = random.random()

    _inter_event_time = -math.log(1.0 - n)/_lambda # gap between successive AC in seconds
    _inter_event_times.append(_inter_event_time) # list of gaps between successive AC in seconds

    _event_time = _event_time + _inter_event_time # arrival time of AC
    _event_times.append(_event_time) # list of arrival times of AC

    print(str(i) +',' + str(_inter_event_time) + ',' + str(_event_time))
```

Comment: Can you be more specific of what list you're trying to access, what code you have used to attempt to access that item, what the error is...?

Comment: `nameoflist[2].methodname()`? This is *really* basic; suggest you run through a tutorial from scratch to fill glaring gaps in knowledge.

Comment: I don't understand it. What `index`? What `index[2]` ?

Answer (score -1):

Please provide some more specific information on what variable in your example you want to retrieve this value. If you want to do it in loop in your last line just use:

`print(str(i) +',' + str(_inter_event_times[i]) + ',' + str(_event_times[i]))`

You can allways use this syntax: `array[index]`